# How to change backend layout in Typo3 7.2?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

I am new to typo3, i am trying to create a new backend layout for my home page.I need add few custom sections to edit contents.I am not able to find option to do so.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 7.2 is out of support and has know security issues. Please update to 7.3 at least.

You can create `backend layout` **records** in any folder in the page tree. To select those `backend layouts`, you have to add this folder as the `general record storage` in the page properties of the page where you want to use your backend layout.
I suggest you take a look into the `Getting started` tutorial which will walk you through your first steps.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/

In case you use a distribution, it might be that the backend layout is added in another way, e.g. via `TSconfig` or directly using PHP. Please consult the according documentation of the distribution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself.

Go to `List` in `Web`, then click on add new `+` icon, then select `Backend Layout` under  `System Records`.